# Gnuplot plotting all datafiles automatically

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have multiple *.data files each has same format and can be plotted with this simple script:

```
cat << __EOF | gnuplot -persist
set terminal pdf
set output 'out.pdf'
set datafile separator ";"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
plot "xxx.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
__EOF
```

How can i automatically make charts for all *.dat files into one pdf? if its not possible to plot all graphs into one file, separate pdfs would be enough.

example .dat file:

```
0;name1;150
1;name2;65
2;name3;81
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append all graphs to a single pdf you must do the iteration over the files inside of the gnuplot script, and set the output file before the loop:

This is the gnuplot script `iterate.gp`

```
set terminal pdf
set output 'out.pdf'
set datafile separator ";"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
files = system('ls *.dat')
do for [file in files] {
    set title file[:strlen(file)-4]
    plot file using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
}
```

Call this with

```
gnuplot iterate.gp
```

Note, that with this solution you cannot have spaces in your data files.

Answer (score 1):

To create multiple pdf files, running this script in the same path with the `*.dat` files worked for me *(make sure no special characters are contained in the `.dat` filenames)*:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r in; do
    out=${in/%.dat/.pdf}
    echo "Converting $in into $out"
    cat << __EOF | gnuplot -persist
    set terminal pdf
    set output "$out"
    set datafile separator ";"
    set boxwidth 0.5
    set style fill solid
    plot "$in" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
__EOF
done < <(ls | grep "\.dat$")
```